# fill a specific amount of rows of data.table with previous value

Tags: r, data.table

I have an issue right now.
the column I am trying to manipulate looks like this:

```
> DT <- data.table(Group= c("SM", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GH", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
> DT
    Group
 1:    SM
 2:  <NA>
 3:  <NA>
 4:  <NA>
 5:  <NA>
 6:  <NA>
 7:    GH
 8:  <NA>
 9:  <NA>
10:  <NA>
11:  <NA>
12:  <NA>
13:  <NA>
14:  <NA>
```

I want to fill the NAs with the previous value but just for a specific amount of rows, in this case just 4, meaning the desired result is:

```
    Group
 1:    SM
 2:    SM
 3:    SM
 4:    SM
 5:    SM
 6:  <NA>
 7:    GH
 8:    GH
 9:    GH
10:    GH
11:    GH
12:  <NA>
13:  <NA>
14:  <NA>
```

how can I achieve this? I tried with na.locf() but it's not doing what I want it to do. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
> DT[, Group := ifelse(seq_len(.N) <= 1 + 4, Group[1], Group),by = cumsum(!is.na(Group))]
> DT
    Group
 1:    SM
 2:    SM
 3:    SM
 4:    SM
 5:    SM
 6:  <NA>
 7:    GH
 8:    GH
 9:    GH
10:    GH
11:    GH
12:  <NA>
13:  <NA>
14:  <NA>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this worked really well and I learned smth new. I made a really dumb mistake at describing my desired result but with the help of your method I was able to produce my desired result with the help of shift(). again, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 4):

An option with `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
DT[,  Group := Group[1][NA^(seq_len(.N) > 5)], cumsum(!is.na(Group))]
DT
#    Group
# 1:    SM
# 2:    SM
# 3:    SM
# 4:    SM
# 5:    SM
# 6:  <NA>
# 7:    GH
# 8:    GH
# 9:    GH
#10:    GH
#11:    GH
#12:  <NA>
#13:  <NA>
#14:  <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Set the threshold
threshold <- 4

DT2 <- DT %>%
  mutate(Group_ID = cumsum(!is.na(Group))) %>%
  group_by(Group_ID) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number() - 1) %>%
  mutate(Group = ifelse(ID <= threshold, first(Group), NA_character_)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Group)
DT2
# # A tibble: 14 x 1
#    Group
#    <chr>
#  1 SM   
#  2 SM   
#  3 SM   
#  4 SM   
#  5 SM   
#  6 NA   
#  7 GH   
#  8 GH   
#  9 GH   
# 10 GH   
# 11 GH   
# 12 NA   
# 13 NA   
# 14 NA
```

Comment: thank you very much, this worked too. I learned smth new today :)